# Why does my Access SQL VBA code jump out of the Sub?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

My code is exiting out of the sub on the line that says "CurrentDb.Execute strSQL_Insert_Data". Do you know why this is happening?

```
  Local_Array = Array("dbo_Tape_Capture_Local_tbl", "dbo_Tape_Local_tbl", "dbo_Tape_Memo_Local_tbl")
  Server_Array = Array("dbo_Tape_Capture", "dbo_Tape", "dbo_Tape_Memo")

For i = 0 To UBound(Local_Array)
    strSQL_Insert_Data = "INSERT INTO [" & Local_Array(i) & "] " & _
                         "SELECT [" & Server_Array(i) & "].* " & _
                         "WHERE (LEFT([" & Server_Array(i) & "].header__situs_loan_id," & _
                          Len([Forms]![Login Page]![CBO_Job_Select_Login]) & ") = " & _
                         "[Forms]![Login Page]![CBO_Job_Select_Login]);"

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL_Insert_Data

CurrentDb.Close

Next i
```

--Added Printed out code--

```
INSERT INTO [dbo_Tape_Capture_Local_tbl] SELECT [dbo_Tape_Capture].*
WHERE (LEFT([dbo_Tape_Capture].header__situs_loan_id,14) = [Forms]![Login Page]![CBO_Job_Select_Login]);
```

Comment: Don't close DB connection inside cycle.

Comment: This is not the simplest code that can reproduce your problem. For example,, what happens if you do the simplest insert possible. Does it work then? If so, your sql is the problem - try printing it out and manually running it. If not, then your db connection could be at fault. Try removing the loop entirely and just to 1 insert. Maybe you don't have permission to insert. Please add more info on what you've tried to narrow the question.

Comment: Hi Bohemian. I have permission. However, I have printed the code to see if you can spot any errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is missing `FROM TableName` in your query. Replace `TableName` with Actual Table Name

```
strSQL_Insert_Data = "INSERT INTO [" & Local_Array(i) & "] " & _
                     "SELECT [" & Server_Array(i) & "].* " & _
                     "FROM [" & Server_Array(i) & "] " & _
                     "WHERE (LEFT([" & Server_Array(i) & "].header__situs_loan_id," & _
                      Len([Forms]![Login Page]![CBO_Job_Select_Login]) & ") = " & _
                     "[Forms]![Login Page]![CBO_Job_Select_Login]);"
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought that should have been included to begin with, however I was testing with the Access Query Builder and it generated something different (didn't include the FROM line). However, your solution worked!

Comment: @ConradAddo Glad to Help You!